# Table cells larger than they are meant to be

Tags: html, css

I've created a map system for a game that runs on the principle of drawing the picture of the map from tiles. There are many reasons for this which I won't go into here but if you really want to know then I'm sure you can find out how to contact me ;)

I have [made the latest version live](http://woarl.com/board/rob.php?mode=map&x=-1&y=9&w=2&h=2) so you can see exactly where the problem lies and the source. The issue is the line between the top 2 tiles and the bottom 2 tiles, I can't figure out why it's gone like this and any help would be appreciated.

In the source is a marker called "stackoverflow", if you search for "stackoverflow" when viewing source then it should take you to the table in question.

I have also uploaded an [image of the issue](http://woarl.com/badMap.png).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you need to use `display: block` on your images. When images are `inline` there's a little extra space for the line spacing.

Answer (score 5):

You could also adjust the line height of the td element:

```css
td {
    line-height: 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this might sound bad, but you need to ensure there is no whitespace between then end of you `<img>` tag and the start of the end `</td>` tag.

i.e. The following will present the problem:

```
<td>
 <img src="image.jpg"/>
</td>
```

And this will not:

```
<td><img src="image.jpg"/></td>
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: OK, that wasn't the solution at all. doh!

Comment: this can present the same/similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked up the whole thing, but the problem lies somewhere in the style sheets.

If you copy out only the table part of it, it is displaying the map correctly.

If you remove the final `</span>` tag from this part, it is also working (however the page gets mixed):

```
<div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>
<div class="content" style="font-size: 1.1em;">

<!-- Stackoverflow findy thingy -->
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

So either try from the beginning with the css or try to remove one-by-one them, to see, which is causing the problem.